# How to use sql in procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE emp_table_001
(
    emp_id NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    emp_name VARCHAR2(50) 
);

INSERT INTO emp_table_001 VALUES(1,'addeesh');
INSERT INTO emp_table_001 VALUES(2,'arunkumar');
INSERT INTO emp_table_001 VALUES(3,'ashok');
INSERT INTO emp_table_001 VALUES(4,'bharath');
INSERT INTO emp_table_001 VALUES(5,'durairaj');

select * from emp_table_001

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_1(employee_id IN NUMBER)
IS
    employee_name VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
SELECT emp_name INTO employee_name FROM emp_table_001
WHERE emp_id = employee_id;

DBMS_OUTPUT_LINE('NAME:'||emp_name);
END;
```

I having trouble with the above code. Error message is this

> Errors: PROCEDURE PROC_1
>   Line/Col: 8/1 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   Line/Col: 8/27 PLS-00201: identifier 'EMP_NAME' must be declared

Comment: In addition to Littlefoot's answer, I would highly recommend you anchor your parameter and variable declarations, ie `employee_id in emp_table_001.emp_id%type` and `employee_name emp_table_001.emp_name%type;` - that way, if you change the size of the columns, you won't need to amend your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_1 (employee_id IN NUMBER)
IS
   employee_name   emp_table_001.emp_name%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT emp_name
     INTO employee_name
     FROM emp_table_001
    WHERE emp_id = employee_id;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('NAME:' || employee_name);   --> this was wrong
END;
```